Create Postgres database with Docker
I am using Spring Boot 3.3.0 and Docker (version 26.1.3, build b72abbb) on Ubuntu OS. I am using the spring-boot-docker-compose dependency so that Spring Boot starts the Docker image automatically when Spring Boot starts up.
pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

I have the following:
Dockerfile
# Use the Amazon Corretto 21 base image
FROM amazoncorretto:21.0.3

# Create a volume for temporary files
VOLUME /tmp

# Arguments for the JAR file to be copied
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 5432

# Copy the JAR file into the Docker image
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar

# Set the entry point for the container to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
    network_mode: host
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=expiry_service_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    network_mode: host

application.properties
spring.application.name=expiry-service
server.port=8080
# expiry_service datasource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/expiry_service_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

When I start the Spring Boot application, it starts up on port 8080:
Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/expiry-service'

I can see that the container has the app and postgres running (Docker Desktop).

However, it hangs for about 2 min (while I think the app tries to connect to postgres). Then the application stops, and the app and postgres stop.

Container Logs
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.558 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.566 UTC [39] FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.566 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.569 UTC [27] LOG:  shutting down
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.572 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
app-1       | 2024-06-07T12:05:29.576Z  INFO 1 --- [expiry-service] [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
postgres-1  | 2024-06-07 12:05:29.600 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres-1 exited with code 0

Spring Boot Logs
org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.ReadinessTimeoutException: Readiness timeout of PT2M reached while waiting for services [expiry-service-app-1]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.ServiceReadinessChecks.waitUntilReady(ServiceReadinessChecks.java:83) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]

Suppressed: org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.ServiceNotReadyException: IOException while connecting to port 8080

    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Question
I have not explicitly created a postgreas database called expiry_service_db, because I expect the Docker image to create one as it is defined in  docker-compose.yml. Is that correct? (In my case, I don't think the expiry_service_db database is being created).
Why does the database shutdown?  I must have configured something in my Docker incorrectly.
Thanks

I doubt it is spring-boot to start the DB container and instead believe you ran docker-compose which started up both app and db containers. But you did not share this bit of information.

When you use network_mode: host port mappings should be ignored because port mappings are mappings between host ports and ports on a bridge network. Yet your screenshots shows that ports are mapped on your containers. Are you sure that your screenshots are from containers started with the compose file you show?

I believe the spring-boot-docker-compose dependency causes Spring to run docker compose up so that it is done each time Spring Boot starts.

Hi Hans, thanks for the reply. Yes I am sure the container expiry-service is from this, because it starts as soon as I start the Spring Boot app. (then times out and stops).

Chicken-egg problem: If spring-boot runs docker-compose up, who started the app container specified in the docker-compose file? Container or not, there must be something else.

At least one of your issues (there are likely several) is that the JDBC URL you gave is definitely wrong:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/expiry_service_db

Every container is network-wise a host of it's own. With localhost the application will never connect to the postgresql container. Instead, use your docker host's IP address (after all you specified the host network).

do I need to map localhost:someip? then change the connection string in application.properties to use the someip?

Must I not use network_mode: host for the app and database?
